# My network switches between 2 different isp

Tags: networking

I live in a building where I have a LAN output in the wall. I simply connect my computer to this output to get internet. I have noticed that multiple times during a day, my network will switch from one ISP to another. They way I noticed this was because I checked on "whatsmyip" website before and after a disconnect/reconnect. I wonder If there is anything from my side that I can do, to prevent switching isp. I have asked landlord for the network administrator. But it was not considered important enough to call "the guy".

I mean if you are just browsing the web, you wouldn't notice. But I play an online game, and when the switch happens I get kicked immediately.

If it is of any help, the building uses a service called Mikrotik. I also have a router (not plugged in at the moment) that I could use, if that is of any help.

Comment: "I have asked for network administrator. But it was not considered important enough to call "the guy"." Nobody can answer your question except your network administrator.

Comment: I see that my sentence was a bit incomplete. I have fixed it. Also, I have no knowledge in this field. I took a chance, thought maybe there was someone else how could help me. But thanks for the reply. @EricF

Comment: You're connecting to a LAN port for your access, yet the network behavior is more like a WiFi connection jumping between two WiFi access networks. Please clarify - does the building have a dedicated broadband connection, or is it WiFi-bridged?  (also, if you've WiFi on your computer, turn it off, just to be sure that's not what you're using).

Answer (score 1):

Many ISPs (Internet Service Providers) assign you a dynamic public IP (Internet Protocol) address, and this address may change at the ISPs whim.

So if you see different IPs on the "whatsmyip" website, that doesn't necessarily mean your ISP changed, only that your IP changed.

The network administrator of your building will likely know about this, but can't do anything about it, because it's up the ISP. [Mikrotik](https://www.mikrotik.com/) is just the company that produces network equipment, not the "service".

You can "tunnel" your internet connection via a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) to another computer with a static IP address, so a dynamic IP change won't be noticed by the game, but it will increase latency, and it will cost money. [Here](https://vpnstaticip.com/) is one such service, google for more.

Comment: I tried the VPN you linked, but it did not solve my problem.